# What are the northeast and southwest bounds in the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

What do these bounds signify ? Is it it some sort of approximation taken from different angles or directions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The north-east and south-west are for creating a rectangle. It constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners. See [LatLngBounds class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds).

If this is still confusing, north-east and south-west are the top-right corner and the bottom-left corner of a rectangle respectively.

It can be used like this:

```
bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.671019, -116.254049),//south west
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.685424, -116.229930) //north east
)
```

A good sample would be [location biasing in Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area) using bounds. If you add a bounds in autocomplete, it will create a rectangle using the south-west and north-east `latlng` and try to search within that rectangle only.

It could also be used for literally drawing a rectangle in map. I have made a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/8c2mdrxh/) in JSBin for you. You can see there that I created a rectangle using bounds. I also plotted 2 markers pointing at the north-east and south-west.